# MATLABにおける２次元配列の宣言について

Tags: array, matlab, データ構造

40000行 x i 列の２次元配列にデータを入れていくコードを書いています。
現在１次元の配列なので、エラーが以下のように出ていますが、MATLABではどのように２次元配列を宣言するのでしょうか。

エラー

```
添字による代入の次元が一致しません。
```

コード

```
num = 3
for i = 1:1:num 
           rxData(i) = event.Data(:, i+1);
end
```

pythonだと

```
for i in range(num):
    list 1 = [[0]*i]*40000
```

で0の40000xi列の２次元配列が作れますが、MATLABでの宣言方法を調べても見つけることができていない状態です。

MATLABドキュメントの[多次元配列](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html)、[行列および配列](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html)は目を通しましたが、宣言方法について細かく明記している箇所がありませんでした。

ご回答を受けて追記
ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。

```
for i = 1:1:num
    rxData = zeros(40000, i);
end

for i = 1:1:num
    rxData(i) = event.Data(:, i+1); 
end
```

とすると
「代入文A(:)= BにおいてAとBの要素数は同じでなければなりません。」

rxData(i) = event.Data(:, i+1); を
rxData(40000, i) = event.Data(:, i+1);とすると

「代入の右辺の次元が、大きさが１でない次元の添字より多くなっています。」
とのエラーが出ている状況です。

for文を書かずに
rxData = event.Data(:, 2); 
とすると40000x1行の変数rxDataには40000x1行のデータが入っていることは確認済みです。

Comment: 追記を見ると、おそらく問題は2次元配列の作り方ではないように思われます。そもそも何をなさりたいのでしょうか。`event.Data`は何次元のデータで、代入先の`rxData`の結果はどうしたいのでしょうか。

Comment: ひょっとして`event.Data`は40000 x numサイズの行列でしょうか。すると`for i = 1:1:num`で`i`が`num`になったとき、`event.Data(:, num+1)`を参照することになり、`num+1`番目の列は存在しないため、値は参照できません。

Comment: event.Dataは40000 x (num +1)の行列ですが、1列目の値は使用しないので2列目から参照しています。

Comment: 元のevent.Data(event.Data(:, num+1))には触れずに、rxDataを使って該当する１列を使って１列目の値との相関を得るために１列を抜き出そうとしています。

Comment: 回答を修正しました。確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。解決しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for`は使わずに一行で

```
rxData = event.Data(:, 2:end);
```

はどうでしょうか。

---

(もったいないので前の回答も残しておきます)

`zeros`という関数があります。例えば

```
zeros(40000,5)
```

で、すべての要素を0で初期化した40000x5の配列が作成されます。三次元配列なら

```
zeros(2,3,4)
```

のように作成できます。

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。追記させていただきました。